# Entity Framework code-first Azure SQL connection in .net Web API

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I am getting below error while connecting to Azure SQL from App Service on Azure. Using ASP.NET WEB API not .net core.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''.
[InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.]

Web.config -

connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxxx;Database=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

TestDBContext.cs -

public TestDBContext() : base("name=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContextName"])
{

```
        var conn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)Database.Connection;
        var credential = new Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" });
        var token = credential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
        conn.AccessToken = token.Token;
    }
```

Comment: Try adding the setting `Persist Security Info = True;` to your connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Getting same error with below connectionString                             connectionString="Server=tcp:test.database.windows.net;Database=test;Persist Security Info=True;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Try adding `Integrity security=true;`

Comment: Tried adding Integrated Security=true; to the conn string.  Getting this error - Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: Use my Erikej.Entityframework.sqlserver package

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication). you could use `Active Directory Default` then specify the client id of the managed identity: `Authentication=Active Directory Default;User Id=<client_id of the user assigned identity>`.

Answer (score 0):

To connect an Azure SQL Server from an Azure asp.net Web API with managed identity authentication, provide the connection string in the following format in Appsettings.json:

```cs
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "QuotesDatabase": "Server=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net,1433; Database=<databasename>;" }
```

Use the code below for the connection:

```cs
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("<connectionstringname>");
                services.AddTransient(a =>{
                    var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                    var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                    var token = credential
                            .GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
                                new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
                    sqlConnection.AccessToken = token.Token;
                    return sqlConnection;
```

[image]

Set admin as desired on the SQL Server:

[image]

Choose an administrator account for Azure service authentication to retrieve the token credentials.

Image for reference:

[image]

Enable the system-assigned managed identity in the "on" state of the Azure app service.

[image]

Log in to the SQL Server with an administrator account, add a user to the database, and assign a role to the user:

```cs
create user [<appName>] from external provider;
alter role db_datareader add member [<appName>];
alter role db_datawriter add member [<appName>];
```

[image]

The database successfully connects to the app.

Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: thanks Bhavani. This is asp.net web api and not .net core. I have edited the original question.

Comment: also you dont need to inject the token manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication

Comment: thanks Thomas. Getting error invalid key Authentication.

Comment: Could you please provide the whole error?